# How to Convert Table design to Div design keeping same cross browser compatible layout?

Tags: css, xhtml, html, cross-browser

Is there any guidelines to convert Table design to Div design keeping same cross browser compatible layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really a guideline but what I would suggest is best practice, use a CSS Framework. Popular frameworks include: -

- [Blueprint](http://www.blueprintcss.org/)
- [960 Grid](http://960.gs/)

For additional information on using CSS frameworks check out [this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/which-css-grid-framework-should-you-use-for-web-design/).

Comment: Is it cross browser compatible?

Comment: Yes. Yes they are. Check each individual framework for specifics on what they do and do not support.

And to those who still support IE6: Abandon all hope ye who enter.